# Remove default html header with typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I use an own extension which generates the html header and this works fine. Only the default header is still generated, so when we look at the page code there are two htlm headers generated. Even if I use the setting below. Any ideas?

```
page = PAGE
page.config {
  noPageTitle = 1
}
```

Comment: `noPageTitle` is for `<title>` tag... check CSS Styled Content for content elements' headers

Comment: But I also mean the `<title>`, that one is this generated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the rewritten question: how to remove the page title tag.

```
config.noPageTitle = 2
```

This is an age-old extravaganza of TypoScript:

https://forge.typo3.org/issues/14929

Answer (score 4):

On the original wording of the question: how to remove page header:

There are two ways, either use

```
page {
    config.disableAllHeaderCode = 1
}
```

or get a copy of `typo3/sysext/cms/tslib/templates/tslib_page_frontend.html`, edit it and enable it via

`config.pageRendererTemplateFile = /your/path` (without `page.`!)

I have stopped doing that (disabling the header) though, as you will miss out on some useful JS TYPO3 creates (email address encryption, FE Login with RSA).

Comment: `disableAllHeaderCode` works only I want to hide only the default `<title>`. Any idee why `noPageTitle` is not working.

Comment: Ah we have to change your question